# How to Register "quartz.dll" by myself?

Tags: c++, directshow

Register a COM, which is mostly regsvr32.exe, but I need to write my own code to Register quartz.dll. So I wrote the following code:

```
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI *FREG)();

BOOL Register()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HMODULE hMod = ::LoadLibrary(L"C:/windows/sysWow64/quartz.dll");
    if (!hMod)
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hResult = ::OleInitialize(NULL);
    if (hResult != S_OK)
    {
        ::FreeLibrary(hMod);
        return FALSE;
    }

FREG lpfunc = (FREG)::GetProcAddress(hMod, "DllRegisterServer");
if (!lpfunc)
{
    ::FreeLibrary(hMod);
    ::OleUninitialize();
    return FALSE;
}

hResult = lpfunc();
::OleUninitialize();
::FreeLibrary(hMod);

return (hResult == S_OK);
}
```

but lpfunc() got E_ACCESSDENIED General access denied error.
 I enabled UAC to requireAdministrator，but nothing changed.

Interestingly, the above code works well in the console program, and there are still permissions issues in the MFC.I found a lot of information, but the problem was not solved .

Comment: This is a mistake, don't mess with OS component installation.  The gritty detail is that not even the SYSTEM account has write access to the existing keys.  Only a special account does, TrustedInstaller.  I think it is used by Windows Update.  This was a hard necessity, DirectShow has had far too much registry hanky-panky trouble in the past.  So, since nobody can mess with it anymore, you no longer need this code.  Yay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't normally want to register quartz.dll. In some rare cases it indeed allows to fix certain issues (esp. related to uninstallation of inaccurately made codec pack). Luckily, there is no harm in re-registration either.

The code is about right except that `OleInitialize` is not really necessary. Unprivileged application cannot write under HKLM and hence the `E_ACCESSDENIED` failure. If you have UAC level reduced to not prompt users to confirm execution of `requireAdministrator` applications, you still have to "run as administrator" in recent OSes or otherwise registry still remains read only for your app and for the DLL you ask to do the registration.

Bottom line, it is still about security and UAC.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My project is a DShow program,and it works well on most machines except on a few unregistered "quartz.dll" machines,If it not be registered,I will got a error when I call graph->RenderStream,I want to solve this problem.

Comment: Machines with quartz.dll unregistered are broken by third party software. An application developer is not supposed to re-register the DLL. There was only one exception in past (years ago!) when Windows Update left the DLL unregistered and this required a manual fix.